# Mongo aggregation to collect array elements based on field name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregated mongo document like below. There are two different batches ("*-Minor" and "*-Major"), and each batch has "batchElements" too.

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "info" : {
        "batch" : "Batch1-Minor"
    },
    "batchElements" : {
        "elements" : [ 
             { },  { }, .... { }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "info" : {
        "batch" : "Batch2-Minor"
    },
    "batchElements" : {
        "elements" : [ 
             { },  { }, .... { }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "info" : {
        "batch" : "Batch3-Major"
    },
    "batchElements" : {
        "elements" : [ 
             { },  { }, .... { }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "info" : {
        "batch" : "Batch4-Major"
    },
    "batchElements" : {
        "elements" : [ 
             { },  { }, .... { }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I collect all "batchElements" of "*-Minor" and "*-Major" and create a document as below;

Output:

```
  {
    "_id" : "123",
    "minorElements" : [
        [{}, {}, {}, ..... {} ], // elements of "Batch1-Minor"
        [{}, {}, {}, ..... {} ], // elements of "Batch2-Minor"
        ...                      // elements of "BatchN-Minor"
    ],
    "majorElements" : [
        [{}, {}, {}, ..... {} ], // elements of "Batch3-Major"
        [{}, {}, {}, ..... {} ], // elements of "Batch4-Major"
        ...                      // elements of "BatchN-Major"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/index.html) to get the "type" of your batch as part of your [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) `_id`. Then you can run another `$group` to make `minor` and `major` parts of the same document. In the last step you need [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) along with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to promote both arrays into root level.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                id: "$_id",
                type: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split: [ { $toLower: "$info.batch" }, "-" ] }, 1 ] }
            },
            docs: { $push: "$batchElements.elements" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.id",
            data: { $push: { k: { $concat: ["$_id.type","Elements"] }, v: "$docs" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ { _id: "$_id" }, { $arrayToObject: "$data" } ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vUAoXUOHvv1)

Comment: in second `group`, what does `$_id.id`?

Comment: References the original `_id` field to be the only grouping key in that stage

Comment: great @mickl , that worked fine. Thank you so much. The elements has an _id field inside. How can I replace the value of every $elements._id field by concatenating $info.batch and $elements._id ? example: "_id": "Batch4-Major-elementId1"

Comment: @Boat `$concat` takes an array of strings so you can add dashes and additional param there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/

Comment: When I tried to assign the concatenated field to a test variable;   "batchElements.elements.test": {
  "$concat": [
    "$info.batch",
    "-",
    "$batchElements.elements._id"
      ]
 }, it did not work. Because the second argument in $concat is an array '$batchElements.elements._id' - how can we represent single Id ?

This I am trying before all the group stages in your answer.

Comment: `$arrayElemAt` takes n-th array element

Comment: inside $concat?

Comment: yes, you can create a Mongo Playground with your current issue and I will try to take a look